# How to mock a static method in scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito, scalatest-maven-plugin

I have a static method in scala and by static method I mean to say that this method is inside an Object named as MyObject. I also have a class named as MyClass where there is a method which calls the method of MyObject internally. I want to write unit test for MyClass and wanted to mock method of MyObject. How can I do this in scala?

```
class MyClass {

  def callMyObject(): String = MyObject.myMethod()

}
```

```
object MyObject {

  def myMethod(): String = "Original method"

}
```

I wish when I call callMyObject() of MyClass it should then return a mocked value instead of "Original method"

I am trying mockStatic and spy but no help.

Comment: I remember trying to do this years ago. Unless something has changed significantly in the past few years, I don't think this is possible. Even if it is, it's not really a good practice. You should rewrite your flow so that you can pass in a function where you need it instead of using a static function. That way you can pass in another function in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

This code requires a little bit of refactoring to make it testable.

First, make the `MyObject` extend a trait. Let's say `MyGenericObject`.

```scala
trait MyGenericObject {
    def sayMyName: Unit
}

object MyObject extends MyGenericObject{
    def sayMyName: Unit = println("foo bar") 
}
```

Then refactor the `MyClass` to take in `myObj: MyGenericObject`.

```scala
class MyClass(myObj: MyGenericObject) {
    def saySomeonesName: Unit = myObj.sayMyName
}
```

Now for testing `MyClass` you can create a new object `MyTestObject` that will extend `MyGenericObject` so that we can pass it to `MyClass`.

```scala
object MyTestObject extends MyGenericObject {
    def sayMyName: Unit = println("test bar") 
}
```

Now for testing.

```scala
val myClass = new MyClass(MyObject)
myClass.saySomeonesName
// Output: foo bar

val myTestClass = new MyClass(MyTestObject)
myTestClass.saySomeonesName
// Output: test bar
```